# Variable in JS from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, variables, smarty

I've seen other similar questions, but I've anyway a problem.

I need to copy an input value every time that it's modified, then do any calculation and then copy the result in a text field. But I'm not able to do it - and I don't know why...

This is my tpl (smarty) code:

```
<label>{l s='Quantity:'}</label>
<input type="text" name="qty" id="quantity_wanted" class="text" onchange="updatevariable(this.value)" value="0" />
{assign var="var1" value=$feature.value|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
<label>{l s='Quantity 2:'}</label><input type="text" name="qty2" id="quantity_wanted2" class="text" value="" />
```

And this is the JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function updatevariable(data) { 
        input = data;   
        var var76 = <?php echo $var1; ?>;
        quantity_wanted2.value = (math.ceil(input*var76))*var76;
    } 
 </script>
```

When I write the var76 line in the JS all doesn't work. Without it, all works (but so I don't have this value, that I need!). What can I do to import this value in the javascript?

Please help me!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: you can't run php in javascript code, Check out ajax which will allow you to pass information from js to the serverside php code

Comment: This will only work if `$var1` is a number if it's not you need to use `json_encode` function.

Comment: @BigT you can put php code inside of html (with .php extension) and javascript can be in html. But you can't put the other way around javascript var to php without ajax.

Comment: @jcubic var1 is a number! But with the "var var76" line the js stops to work...

Comment: @BigT I tried also JSON, but maybe I'm not good... it was the first time I tried it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it in this way if both code present in single tpl

```
 {literal}
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function updatevariable(data) { 
            input = data;   
 {/literal}
            var var76 = {$var1} ;
{literal}
            quantity_wanted2.value = (math.ceil(input*var76))*var76;
        } 
     </script>
 {/literal}
```

Comment: Excuse me...I was in error...it doesn't work... And doesn't work also with the {literal} :(

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a Smarty variable in the HTML and echoing a PHP variable in the JS code. This suggests to me that the two are in different files, meaning different scopes. How would this completely different file know of the var1-variable in your template? It's as if you would go to your mom and tell her a secret number between 1 and 100 and then go to your dad to ask him which number you told your mom. He can't know.

If you look at your generated javascript file, you `var var76 =` line probably looks like `var var76 = ;` which correctly yields a syntax error.

The way to solve this would be to put the javascript in the same file as your Smarty template, somewhere below your `{assign}` line.

Having said that: your code looks like a pain to debug later on. Variables named var1 up to var76? Do you know off of the top of your head what variable 65 stands for? The same goes for your `updatevariable` function: the name does nothing to describe what the function actually does.

Comment: It's all in the same file...so @Rohit solved it! Thank you very much!!